# Button that makes textarea text bold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that has an `onclick="bold()"` and it is supposed to be changing the font weight from normal to bold and then back to normal. It isn't doing anything though. What do I need to change or add? Here is a jsfiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/dZVfh/

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('description-box');
    function bold() {
      if( $(x).css("font-weight") == "normal") {
        $(x).css("font-weight"), "bold");
      }
      else {
        $(x).css("font-weight", "normal");
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code:

Change

`$(x).css("font-weight"), "bold");`

to

`$(x).css("font-weight", "bold");`

---

**Full function**

```
function bold() {
    var x = $('#description-box');
    if (x.css("font-weight") !== "bold") {
        x.css("font-weight", "bold");
    } else {
        x.css("font-weight", "normal");
    }
}
```

---

**Working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dZVfh/3/

There were a number of problems in your original fiddle.

- jQuery was not being included
- The function was defined inside `domReady` - which means it isn't visible when clicking the button
- The CSS block had a syntax error. The style was being closed with a `)` instead of a `}`
- You were trying to assign the element to `x` before the DOM was ready. The new fiddle does this inside the function (by which time the DOM is ready)

Comment: Looks like the issue is that you are trying to assign the element to `x` before the DOM is ready. Replacing the script block with the above edit.should work.

Comment: A lot of remarks in the answer but not what was really important it's not there. A pity.

Comment: @Alexander - Did i miss out any important detail? Let me know. I'll be happy to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

i prefer to have it change class :

add this style

```
.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

change your function :

```
function bold(){
  if( $(x).hasClass("bold")) {
     $(x).removeClass("bold");
  }
  else {
    $(x).addClass("bold");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can shorten this `function bold(){$(x).toggleClass('bold')}`